# server certificate verification failed. CAfile: ca.pem CRLfile: none

Tags: c++, linux, libcurl

I want to make https tests using libcurl and openssl in c++.
 I have the following code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(mEasyHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(mEasyHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2L);
result = curl_easy_setopt(mEasyHandle, CURLOPT_CAINFO , "ca.pem");
```

I have a Windows server that listens on `192.168.0.101:4443`. When running the program from Visual Studio, the certificate verification works, but on Linux I get the error **`server certificate verification failed. CAfile: ca.pem CRLfile: none`**.

In `ca.pem` I have put the content generated in the server's certificate (testing on windows works, on Linux not).

```
* Trying 192.168.0.101...
* Connected to 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101) port 4443 (#0)
* found 1 certificates in ca.pem
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: ca.pem CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 0
```

***UPDATE***:

I have a folder `/etc/ssl/certs` that contains a lot of ca certs files. I have copied `ca.pem` to `/etc/ssl/certs` and run **`update-ca-certificates`** which produced the output:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done. Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
```

Comment: Are you sure it's port `4443` and not `443` (which is the default HTTPS port)?

Comment: I have a custom server taht listens on the port 4443.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/570888/download-01-org-certificate-verification-failed-crlfile-missing. Obviously, replacing `download.01.org` with your remote hostname.

Comment: I don't have installed curt or openssl. I use the libraries in c++ (libcurl, libssl, libcrypt). I set the path to my ca trust store (curl_easy_setopt(mEasyHandle, CURLOPT_CAINFO , "ca.pem")). But i have basically did the same thing but manually as they explain in http://askubuntu.com/questions/570888/download-01-org-certificate-verification-failed-crlfile-missing. I have at the server side a certificate server.pem and i have copied the section between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/-----END CERTIFICATE-----" to ca.pem.

Comment: Please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it. My suspicion: if `192.168.0.101` is *not* listed in the *`Subject Alternate Name`* section, then its going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. Was a certificate problem in fact. The code worked but the timestamp on the machine was before the certificate was generated.